# WPFMediaKit XAML error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-mediakit

I am trying to view a webcam in WPF.  I have added the reference in my XAML as follows:

```
xmlns:WPFMediaKit="clr-namespace:WPFMediakit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"
```

and then inserting the control as follows:

```
<WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement></WPFMediaKit:VideoCaptureElement>
```

The project compiles fine and displays the webcam but in the design editor it gives me an "Invalid Markup" error and doesn't allow me to edit it.  Mousing over the XAML for the control gives the following error:

> The name "VideoCaptureElement" does not exist in the namespace
>   "clr-namespace:WPFMediakit.DirectShow.Controls;assembly=WPFMediaKit"

I am stumped any ideas?

Comment: Try Clean and Rebuild on the project/solution.  I don't experience this issue on Win 7 .NET 4.5.

Comment: Are you building an x64 configuration on VS 2010? Its designer doesn't support it well.